# How to make an HTTP GET Request with Parameters. SwiftyJSON Swift

Tags: swift, swifty-json

Below mentioned snippet is working just fine. It queries JSON data. I just want to know how can I pass parameters with this.

```
let filePath = NSURL(string: "http://localhost:2403/postedjob")
let jsonData = NSData(contentsOfURL:filePath!)
let json = JSON(data: jsonData!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments, error: nil)
```

I want to pass this parameters:

```
let params = ["$limit": 2, "$sort": ["id":"+1"]] as Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
```

Answer (score 0):

For a GET request pass parameters in the query string (the part after the "?" mark).

For a POST request parameters can be sent in the `body` in a number of ways. Raw data, form data and JSON among other methods.

Of course the server has to match the method used.

Answer (score 0):

Alamofire may be a good option for you to pass the parameters.

https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire

Comment: thanks for your reply.! But I can't use Alamofire in my case.

Comment: I don't want blocks and closures.